# laravel - получение данных из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, laravel

Есть две таблицы `users` и `posts`

В `posts` есть столбец `user_id`

Как по `user_id` получить всю информацию об `users` и что бы это было привязано к своему `posts`

т.е код таков:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="content" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
    <header>{{ $post->title }}</header>
    <div class="body">{{ $post->body }}</div>
    <div class="info">
        Дата: {{ $post->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}
        *инфа о пользователе*
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, решил свой вопрос.
Кому интересно:

```
//Post
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
//View
$post->user->whatEverUserInfo;
```

Comment: И выборку сразу делайте с with `Post::with('users')` иначе в цикле на каждую итерацию будете в базу ходить.

Comment: Да, я изначально в документации увидел это и сделал, но спасибо что предупредили)